# Usando Proguard com Maven em libs no java swing

Tags: java, swing, maven, proguard

Eu ofusquei meu jar utilizando o plugin proguard-maven-plugin, o pom.xml e a configuração são estes:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <maxMemory>1024m</maxMemory>
                <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

O arquivo proguard.conf onde estão as configurações do proguard:

```
-keep public class br.com.myapp.myapp.Main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Com isso eu consigo ofuscar meu código fonte no jar gerado pela compilação, porém não consigo mais utilizar o jar como lib nos meus outros projetos, pois as classes desaparecem.

Minha pergunta é: como faço para ofuscar o jar mas que este ainda possa ter seus métodos utilizados por outras aplicações como uma lib externa numa aplicação swing?

[Documentação](http://wvengen.github.io/proguard-maven-plugin/) do plugin.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Dê uma se [essa configuração](https://github.com/facebookarchive/proguard/blob/master/examples/library.pro) resolve o problema.

Comment: @Renan essa configuração funciona, mas se eu oculto os métodos que utilizo em outro projeto, estes ainda ficam inacessíveis.